# Unable to connect to styled receiver

Tags: javascript, google-cast

I am trying to build a simple JS based web app that starts a styled media receiver(hosted by Google, reads your custom CSS file). I have a developer account set up and have gone through adding the app in my account. I made sure to select the "Styled Media Receiver" type when I created it.

I am using the basic setup described [here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender) to construct my sender. I was able to get this code to work with a custom receiver. I can see in my log that the extension is detected.

```
Found cast extension: boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd
```

I set up my session request with the app ID provided on the Cast developer's console.

```
var sessionRequest = new chrome.cast.SessionRequest(id);
```

Then I call:

```
var apiConfig = new chrome.cast.ApiConfig(this.sessionListener.bind(this),
                                          this.receiverListener.bind(this));
```

Which returns the value "unavailable" to the "receiverListener" function. When I try to request a session it returns the error callback with the following data:

```
Object {code: "receiver_unavailable", description: null, details: null}
```

So, I am trying to figure out what I might be missing. Like I said I've used the same code to launch a custom receiver successfully. Here is the full code that I am using:

```
Polymer({
  ready: function(){
    window['__onGCastApiAvailable'] = function(loaded, errorInfo){
      if(loaded){
        this.initCast();
      }
      else{
        console.log(errorInfo);
      }
    }.bind(this);
  },
  initCast: function(){
    var id = "731AC858";
    var sessionRequest = new chrome.cast.SessionRequest(id);
    var apiConfig = new chrome.cast.ApiConfig(sessionRequest,
                                              this.sessionListener.bind(this),
                                              this.receiverListener.bind(this));
    chrome.cast.initialize(apiConfig, 
                           this.initCastSuccess.bind(this), 
                           this.initCastError.bind(this));
  },
  initCastSuccess: function(){
    this.castReady = true;
  },
  initCastError: function(e){
    console.log(e);
  },
  startCast: function(){
    chrome.cast.requestSession(this.startCastSuccess.bind(this), 
                               this.startCastError.bind(this));
  },
  startCastSuccess: function(e){
    console.log(e);
  },
  startCastError: function(e){
    console.log(e); //returns Object {code: "receiver_unavailable", description: null, details: null} when "startCast" is called.
  },
  sessionListener: function(e){
  console.log(e);
  },
  receiverListener: function(e){
    console.log(e);//returns "unavailable"
  },
});
```

Comment: Are you writing a chrome/packaged app?

Comment: No, it's a web app using polymer and deployed on Google App Engine. Also, the result is the same on the local development server or on the deployed server.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like I was either being impatient and it takes a while for the app to digest, or the server that hosts the Styled media receiver was down for a while. I tried it today and everything is working great.

**----UPDATE----**

I just tried creating a fresh styled media receiver app, and I can't get it to connect. So my guess is that there is something that has to be prepped before you can start using it.